# How can i shorten or simplify my jquery statements?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a custom dropdown that I made, just wondering if I could get some advice as how to shorten / simplify my jQuery code. I have two lists that do the same thing and I have the code duplicated, which i know is long winded and really not a good approach.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/22/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-select list-one">
    <span>Select Option</span>
    <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
        <li>List Item 4</li>
        <li>List Item 5</li>
        <li>List Item 6</li>
        <li>List Item 7</li>
        <li>List Item 8</li>
        <li>List Item 9</li>
        <li>List Item 10</li>
        <li>List Item 11</li>
        <li>List Item 12</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="custom-select list-two">
    <span>Select Option</span>
    <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
        <li>List Item 4</li>
        <li>List Item 5</li>
        <li>List Item 6</li>
        <li>List Item 7</li>
        <li>List Item 8</li>
        <li>List Item 9</li>
        <li>List Item 10</li>
        <li>List Item 11</li>
        <li>List Item 12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//Function for .list-one
$(function() {

    $('.custom-select.list-one').click(function() {
        $('.custom-select.list-one ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.custom-select.list-one ul li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.custom-select.list-one span')
        .html($('.custom-select.list-one ul li.selected').html());
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

});

// Function for .list-two
$(function() {

    $('.custom-select.list-two').click(function() {
        $('.custom-select.list-two ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.custom-select.list-two ul li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.custom-select.list-two span')
        .html($('.custom-select.list-two ul li.selected').html());
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

});
```

Any advice, thanks!

-Big D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following seems to work:

```
$(function() {

    $('.custom-select').click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.custom-select ul li').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('div').find('span').html($this.html());
    });

});
```

The idea is that you don't need to know which of the selects was clicked on: whichever it is, you just find its child ul element using `$(this).find()` and then toggle that. Similarly, when a li is clicked you just find the div element it belongs to with `.closest()` (you could also use `.parent().parent()`) and then from there find the associated span element.

I also store a reference to the object returned by `$(this)` rather than recreating it each time you need it.

I noticed you were adding a "selected" class to the clicked li element only for use as a selector immediately afterwards, and then removing it again - you don't need it at all since you already have a reference to the clicked element in `this`.

Note also that you don't need two document.ready handlers: even for your code as you had it with the repetition you could've defined all of your click handlers within a single document.ready.

Also I wouldn't use a class (like your "list-one" and "list-two") to uniquely identify each list: that's what the id attribute is for.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/25/

Comment: n, thank you, that really shortens it! do you know how i would be able to re-initialize this script? if i put it in a pop up dialog, it works, but then i close the dialog and re-open it again and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I'm not sure - I think I'd need to see it in context. If closing the dialog actually removes those elements then you'd need to either re-run the above when the dialog opens and the elements are recreated or use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or (if using jQuery version >= 1.7) the `.delegate()` equivalent syntax of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handlers that will apply even to elements created later.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can define a single javascript function with a parameter to help you identify which list to work with.

```
// Function Definition
function doListStuff(listClass) {

    $(listClass).click(function() {
        $(listClass + ' ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $(listClass +' ul li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(listClass + ' span')
        .html($(listClass + ' ul li.selected').html());
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

}

//Function for .list-one
$(function() {
    doListStuff('.custom-select.list-one');
});

//Function for .list-two
$(function() {
    doListStuff('.custom-select.list-two');
});
```

**Edit - Updated my code to work (actually tested it this time!)
** http://jsfiddle.net/3zL6t/5/

Comment: You could make it shorter if you put both calls to `doListStuff()` inside the same document.ready handler...

Comment: Thanks for the help tyler, it helped a lot!